# Json Post size limit increase in MVC 4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, json.net

I have seen & tried a lot of codes to increase the JSON limit like in
1. web.config
      `<system.web.extensions>
      <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
      </webServices>
      </scripting>
     </system.web.extensions>`

2.JSonControllerFactory

```
    public sealed class CustomJsonValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{

    private static void AddToBackingStore(Dictionary<string, object> backingStore, string prefix, object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> d = value as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (d != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in d)
            {
                AddToBackingStore(backingStore, MakePropertyKey(prefix, entry.Key), entry.Value);
            }
            return;
        }

        IList l = value as IList;
        if (l != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
            {
                AddToBackingStore(backingStore, MakeArrayKey(prefix, i), l[i]);
            }
            return;
        }

        // primitive
        backingStore[prefix] = value;
    }
```

> Down here in GetDeserializedObject() i am getting **bodytext** as empty and unable to set the max property.

```
    private static object GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        if (!controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // not JSON request
            return null;
        }

        StreamReader reader = new    StreamReader(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
        string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bodyText))
        {
            // no JSON data
            return null;
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue; //increase MaxJsonLength.  This could be read in from the web.config if you prefer
        object jsonData = serializer.DeserializeObject(bodyText);
        return jsonData;
    }

}
```

script [down **data: jQuery("#geomaster").serialize()** contains data. If it is below 100 points the data is saving successfully. if it crosses 100 points, not hitting the controller SaveGeodata method(i mean not posting to controller)].

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "SaveGeodata",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: jQuery("#geomaster").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Geofence Created Successfully");

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Error");
            }

        });
```

Is there any way where i can attach the maxJsonSize property in script itself. 
Any other possible means which could help in posting max data to controller is really thankful.

Comment: Have you tried setting processData to false in your ajax request?  By default, jQuery tries to process this data into objects, but since you are sending a pre-processed string you don't want this.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch:  tried  processData: false , no change.